# mywebsite.com/project.php?id=123 should redirect via .htaccess to mywebsite.com/123

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, redirect

**mywebsite.com/123** should display content via .htaccess of **mywebsite.com/project.php?id=123** - unfortunately I changed the .htaccess rewriterule yesterday for anothe reason and now the redirection does not function (it goes to our 404-error page). Can you see what I've done wrong here? Many thanks!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Does `123.php` really exist? Because that's where your code snippet redirects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the last line to this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

if you want the regex rule not to catch URLs that contain alphabetic characters, use

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9\-_]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

And for your new requirement:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9\-_]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-_]+)/?$ new.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: And then he should update his links to go to mysite.com/number instead of mysite.com/project.php?id=number

Comment: Both of those are perfect! I need to add a condition though which I should have outlined in the original post. While we need the reditrect as explained, we also have actual php pages such as "new.php" that are shown by going to "/new" for example. So I need to run both of the rules you wrote above - how can I put them so they both function?

Comment: Yes, ulvund, that is how the site is set-up... but after changing the htaccess yesterday I lost the functionality and had no record of the changes (schoolboy error, I know).

Comment: @JoeW just use the first one then

Comment: Unfortunately while that works for the project.php?id=123 pages it fails and returns a 404-error when trying to access "new" (which uses content from "new.php").

Comment: OK, I can see what's happening here... lower in our .htaccess file we have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ project.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` which has not been changed - it's the same as your idea. However, the problem now that something in those beginning lines shown in my original post do not allow "new" to pull content from "new.php", instead favouring a 404-error page. Any ideas? If you want to go to the chat I can show you the full code.

Comment: @Joe you would have to build two rules, one for alphanumerics (`a-z`, remove `0-9`) pointing to new.php, and the second rule in the list. That should work. I added an example

Comment: I probably didn't explain that very well - only project.php uses id's, new.php/contact.php (and many more) simply need to be stripped of their file extension (to new/contact) as that is how we have the links set-up on the site.

Comment: It's ok, panic over... I've inserted this at the top of the file:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`